# Facebook send plugin href truncated

Tags: facebook, send

I'm using the Facebook send plugin (the HTML5 code) with the following code:

```
<div class="fb-send" data-href="http://www.stylesays.com/stores/10corsocomo-theshoponline.com/41136/"></div>
```

When I click on the send, the href appears to have been truncated to only http://www.stylesays.com. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance - I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having similar issues, although I believe yours is to do with a redirect.

If I visit the URL you have posted, it redirects to:
http://www.stylesays.com/#!/stores/10corsocomo-theshoponline.com/41136/

Have you tried using that URL instead?

Comment: Thanks! I'm kinda embarrassed and surprised that that was the problem - but anyways, huge thanks! That fixed it.